# Content always centered in Dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui, center

Can somebody help me to always (also after re-sizing the Dialog) center my content in the dialog? The two text-fields should be side by side.

Have a look at my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/65FUA/.

Thank you very much for your help!

Regards shub

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use `float: left`?

Here's a solution using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/MLnX6/1/

Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

I moved your input styles to the CSS for ease of reading.

Basically add a fixed width (I figured out the best width is 387px) and `margin: 0 auto;` to your `<form>` element.

```
form
{
    width: 387px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form input
{
    float: left;
}
```

It's worth noting that in Firefox, it doesn't seem to work as in Chrome (Which I tested in) Just increase the width by a few pixels and it will work in FF too.

http://jsfiddle.net/65FUA/2/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `style="float: left"` from input controls and add this in a stylesheet (or style tags):

```
#div1
{
    text-align:center;

}
```